# Breaking a loop after resolving a promise

Tags: automated-testing, javascript, cypress, api-automation

I am writing a program to check the health endpoint of one of our APIs. So, before starting execution, I try to hit the health endpoint 5 times. If I get the desired response code during the 5 attempts, I break the loop and start test execution else give a message saying API is not healthy and stop the execution.

When below function is executed, it results in an error saying `unsyntactic break`
Can someone suggest a better way to address this? I am using cypress.

```
  const maxRetry = Cypress.env('maxWarmUpRetries');
  const sleepTimeMs = 200;
  console.log(chalk.yellow('Checking API health before test execution...'));
  let healthCheckResponse;
  let healthStatusCode;
  for (let i = 0; i < maxRetry; i++) {
    console.log('Value of i is: ',i)
    apiHelper.requestHealth.then(response=>{
      healthCheckResponse=response;
      console.log('healthCheckStatusCode: ',healthCheckResponse.status)
      if (healthCheckResponse) {
        healthStatusCode = healthCheckResponse.status;
        if (healthStatusCode === 200) {
          console.log(chalk.green('API is healthy, moving forward with execution >>'));
          break;
        } else {
          console.log(chalk.yellow('Warm up - Checking API /health before test execution...'));
          if (i === maxRetry - 1) {
            console.log(chalk.red('Warm up - API /health is down!!! Suspending test execution.'));
            break;
          }
        }
      } else {
        console.log(chalk.yellow('Warm up - Checking API /health before test execution...'));
        if (i === maxRetry - 1) {
          console.log(chalk.red('Warm up - API /health is down!!! Suspending test execution.'));
          break;
        }
      }
    })
    
  }
});
```

Comment: That break is inside a callback function, not the same scope the loop is in. Your loop doesn't even wait for the request before iterating. Can you use async/await instead?

Comment: Well. Cypress is not liking async/await. I was using supertest earlier and this one worked flawlessly with async/await. But not with Cypress.

Comment: Looks like they recommend recursion: https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq.html#Can-I-make-cy-request-poll-until-a-condition-is-met.

Comment: I would say this question should be closed because it's about JS coding, it should be reposted on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Did the answer help

Comment: This is fundamentally flawed JavaScript.IMHO  Its not about Cypress or super test libraries, its about JavaScript.

Comment: Please read on how JavaScript is different and fundamentally works asynchronously .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here is how this was finally fixed. Using `await` was one step closer to the solution.
However, it was `cypress-promise` that helped in fixing the issue. Click [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-promise?activeTab=readme) to read more about `cypress-promise`. Now the code looks like this:

```
const sleepTimeMs = 500;
console.log(chalk.yellow('Checking API health before test execution...'));
let healthCheckResponse;
let healthStatusCode;
for (let i = 0; i < maxRetry; i++) {
  healthCheckResponse = await promisify(apiHelper.requestApiHealth());
  if (healthCheckResponse) {
    healthStatusCode = healthCheckResponse.status;
    if (healthStatusCode === 200) {
      console.log(chalk.green('API is healthy, moving forward with execution >>'));
      break;
    } else {
      console.log(chalk.yellow('Warm up - Checking API /health before test execution...'));
      if (i === maxRetry - 1) {
        console.log(chalk.red('Warm up - API /health is down!!! Suspending test execution.'));
        break;
      }
      cy.wait(sleepTimeMs);
    }
  } else {
    console.log(chalk.yellow('Warm up - Checking API /health before test execution...'));
    if (i === maxRetry - 1) {
      console.log(chalk.red('Warm up - API /health is down!!! Suspending test execution.'));
      break;
    }
    cy.wait(sleepTimeMs);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For loops are problematic in Cypress because they run run faster than the Cypress command queue.

You don't show the Cypress commands above, but I assume they are following the warmup loop and are only called when `healthStatusCode === 200`.

You might find [**Test Retries**](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/test-retries.html#Individual-Test-s) will work better for you.

> **Individual Test(s)**
>
> If you want to configure retry attempts on a specific test, you can set this by using the test’s configuration.

There is good logging out of the box, so you could drop your additional logs.

```javascript
const maxRetry = Cypress.env('maxWarmUpRetries');

it('allows user to login', {
  retries: { runMode: maxRetry, openMode: maxRetry }
}, () => {

  apiHelper.requestHealth.then(response=>{

    // force test retry by throwing an error
    if (!response || response.status !== 200) {
      throw new Error("test fails here")
    }

    // All good
    // run tests here

  })
})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Break should be inside a loop, you are calling break inside a callback function , this is why you are getting unsyntactic break

if you want to break from call back replace break with **return** but this won't break the outside for loop.

**you should use await :**

```
  for (let i = 0; i < maxRetry; i++) {
    console.log('Value of i is: ',i)
    healthCheckResponse= await apiHelper.requestHealth()
    healthStatusCode = healthCheckResponse.code 
          if (healthCheckResponse) {
        healthStatusCode = healthCheckResponse.status;
        if (healthStatusCode === 200) {
          console.log(chalk.green('API is healthy, moving forward with execution >>'));
          break;
        } else {
          console.log(chalk.yellow('Warm up - Checking API /health before test execution...'));
          if (i === maxRetry - 1) {
            console.log(chalk.red('Warm up - API /health is down!!! Suspending test execution.'));
            break;
          }
        }
      } else {
        console.log(chalk.yellow('Warm up - Checking API /health before test execution...'));
        if (i === maxRetry - 1) {
          console.log(chalk.red('Warm up - API /health is down!!! Suspending test execution.'));
          break;
        }
      }
```

Note: To use await the IT block or function inside which you are calloing this code should be declared as asyn

eg:

```
it('should edit a new item', async () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < maxRetry; i++) {
        console.log('Value of i is: ',i)
        healthCheckResponse= await apiHelper.requestHealth
        healthStatusCode = healthCheckResponse.code 
              if (healthCheckResponse) {
            healthStatusCode = healthCheckResponse.status;
            if (healthStatusCode === 200) {
              console.log(chalk.green('API is healthy, moving forward with execution >>'));
              break;
            } else {
              console.log(chalk.yellow('Warm up - Checking API /health before test execution...'));
              if (i === maxRetry - 1) {
                console.log(chalk.red('Warm up - API /health is down!!! Suspending test execution.'));
                break;
              }
            }
          } else {
            console.log(chalk.yellow('Warm up - Checking API /health before test execution...'));
            if (i === maxRetry - 1) {
              console.log(chalk.red('Warm up - API /health is down!!! Suspending test execution.'));
              break;
            }
          }
}
```

Comment: Please add a sensible command when downvoting

Comment: Why do you need a loop here at all?

Comment: @vishal author need to loop till the response is 200 if it's not 200 then try again till it is 200

Comment: @VishalAggarwal in the question the loop is not to wait till promise resolve , it is to retry till status is 200

Comment: why would I run a test again and again until I get an expected result ?If it fails, it fails. Are we warming up the API by multiple calls? 

Comment: That api is not in the focus of test  author needs it to return 200 within max try and do something with it . There is no assertions , so it's out of scope of this answer . This answer is about how to run the loop till 200 is returned .

Comment: It block is just an example it can be hook , or spec or any other async function

Comment: So, from experience, we have observed that sometimes APIs fail during first 1 or 2 attempts when hit first time in the pipeline. So,we add this warm up code that tries to hit the api. We call it warm up calls and generally perform this on health or ping endpoint of API under test. If the API doesn't return 200 in 5 attempts we don't start the test execution. But, if this code is not there we might end up getting false negatives couple of times.

Comment: @PDHide, I will check your answer this weekend. Sorry for the delay in response.

Comment: @VishalAggarwal, please read. Warm up concept is used while automating API endpoints as well. Ensuring that API is warm before starting test execution. https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/performance/configure/test-warmup.html